# Replace words dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this line of code

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/1800/g,'6:00pm'));
```

I can replace the word, but how can I make it more dynamic with this script?

```
var getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime){
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0,2));
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
```

My HTML code is e.g

```
Your class will start at 1900, please be there by 1845.
```

Which will be counted to

```
Your class will start at 07:00pm, please be there by 06:45pm.
```

I tried this:

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(fourDigitTime, getFormattedTime(fourDigitTime)));

var fourDigitTime = document.getElementById('fourDigitTime').value;

var getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime){
var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0,2));
var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
```

It does not work..

Comment: are you getting errors now?

Comment: Where are you using getFormattedTime function?

Comment: The 2 codes are separate, I want to be able to change the time to 3:00pm if the time is 1500. Or any other converted time..

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415618/replace-military-time-to-normal-time-with-javascript asked by the same user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edited after EmersonF cleared up that **all** four letter times should be replaced]

You can use a function as the second argument to replace:

```
function formatTime(str, p1) {
   // do something with p1
   return // the formated time
}

$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/(\d?\d\d\d)/g, formatTime));
```

The part of the string that is "captured" using the parenthesis in the
regular expression is handed to the function as the second argument (here called p1)

See http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/pb8d2/ for a working example

Note: the regular expression cannot tell the year 2015 apart from quater
past 8pm, and will convert the year to a time!

Comment: My page actually consist of many 4digit number which I need to change as and when needed. Not just one occurrence. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: so your question is actually "how do i replace every occurence of a four digit time in my page by an am/pm formatted time?"

Comment: Yes, and to replace every occurrence of 4 digit time of any type. The fiddle I saw is only working on 1800 but not any other digits..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var time = "1500";

$("body").html($("body").html().replace(time, getFormattedTime(time)));
```

`replace()` need not be always `regex`.