# Replace military time to normal time with Javascript

Tags: javascript

With this script

```
getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime){
var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0,2));
var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
```

I can change 4 digit time to normal clock time (there is a problem with 0930 though..)

And with this

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/1135/g,'11:35am'));
```

To replace any occurange of 1135 in my page.

However, in my page, I have a list of time in tables. I need to convert them e.g.

```
Class starts at 1700, please be there by 1630 and sign in by 1645.
```

It should translate into

```
Class starts at 05:00pm, please be there by 04:30pm and sign in by 04:45pm.
```

Comment: What if the text is `The class will have 1000 lessons. It will start at 1700, please be there by 1630 and sign in by 1645.`? That would change to `The class will have 10:00pm lessons. It will start...`

Comment: The `parseInt` function should **always** be passed a second argument to avoid the goofy octal interpretation of strings starting with "0". (The second argument should be `10` unless you know you're parsing strings representing a different base.)

Comment: noted that other text in the page will affect it, and I will try to resolve that later on. I can maybe put it encasing in elementID, e.g. <td id="militaryTime">1450</td> since it will be in td tags

Comment: If you can control the HTML, why not just output the correctly formatted time in the first place?

Comment: Because due to the software we are using, it does not support time. The workaround is storing 24hr time so that our classes can be listed according to the assending 4 digit number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the only digits displayed in the text are the times you can use:

```
var txt = 'Class starts at 0845, please be there by 1630 and sign in by 1645.'

getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime) {
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0, 2),10);
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
/* replace numeric entities*/
var newTxt = txt.replace(/(\d+)/g, function (match) {
    return getFormattedTime(match)
})
$('body').html(newTxt);
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/q6HC9/1

EDIT: Wrapping times in a tag would greatly simplify situation. Wrap all military times in a span with a common class and then use the `html()` method

```
<span class="mil_time">0845</span>
```

```js
getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime) {
    /* make sure add radix*/
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0, 2),10);
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
/* find all spans and replace their content*/
$('span.mil_time').html(function( i, oldHtml){
   return getFormattedTime(oldHtml);
})
```

Comment: I tried it in the fiddle, doesn't seem to work. Is this wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/q6HC9/2/
From Bergi's suggestion, I might actually use <time></time> tags. How can I do that?

Comment: was a typo in my `.html()` code ..left out `function`  Working demo..http://jsfiddle.net/q6HC9/3/

Comment: Finally, after 6 hours of trying! I really learnt something from here!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime){
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0,2), 10);
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};

s = "Class starts at 1700, please be there by 1630 and sign in by 1645.";

c = s.replace(/([^\d]*)([0-9]{4})([^\d]*)/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + getFormattedTime(p2) + p3
});

console.log(c);
```

Output:

```
Class starts at 5:00pm, please be there by 4:30pm and sign in by 4:45pm.
```

**Update**

In your case:

```
s = $("body").html();

c = s.replace(/([^\d]*)([0-9]{4})([^\d]*)/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + getFormattedTime(p2) + p3
});

$("body").html(c);
```

**Update 2**

If you have the time inside `<td class="fourDigitTime">1500</td>`, then use this:

```
$(".fourDigitTime").each(function() {
    $(this).text(getFormattedTime($(this).text());
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6HC9/44/)

Comment: You need the second argument to `parseInt()`!

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that my text is in HTML. The main problem is getting all the 4 digits to change.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: "Be there exactly at 1200!" "1000 is the time we start"

Comment: I think I should not use $("body").html(); as it took in all the HTML tags, tables and stuff. The 4 digits are in <td id="fourDigitTime"></d>. So I did this:

Comment: s = document.getElementById('fourDigitTime').innerHTML;
alert(s);
c = s.replace(/([\s,])([0-9]{4})([\s\.,])/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + getFormattedTime(p2) + p3
});

document.getElementById('fourDigitTime').innerHTML = c;

Comment: @EmersonF do you only have the time inside the `td` fourDigitTime?

Comment: Yes, or I can also follow Bergi's suggestion to use <time></time>

Comment: Try my updated answer... Also, in the code you seem to use `</d>` instead of TD.

Comment: It is better to avoid custom HTML tags.

Comment: Will this only be changing 3 times? We have a list of times in the whole page. very confused now..

Comment: The `Update 2` will change all the items which have `id="fourDigitTime"`, do you want this?

Comment: Its okay, a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/q6HC9/3/ It's very similiar to your solution. Just difference in variables :D

Comment: You cannot use `id` because there can be only one element with an id, use `class` instead. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your regular expression to match 4 digits, and then your `getFormattedTime` function as a replacement function to [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
$('body').html(function(_, old) {
    return old.replace(/\b\d{4}\b/g, getFormattedTime);
});
```

Please notice also the comments by @Doorknob and @Pointy. To replace only time "numbers", you will need to markup them semantically, for example with html5 [`<time>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element):

```html
Class starts at <time>1700</time>, please be there by <time>1630</time> and sign in by <time>1645</time>.
```

```js
$('time').text(function(_, old) {
    return getFormattedTime(old);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get this.. i even tried getFormattedTime(time) to no avail..

Comment: What part did you not get? The examples might not have worked before I added the `index` parameters