# Display Time in 12 Hour Format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to display Time in 12 hour format by altering the following code.
 i Tried Various Techniques but no luck, hope to find The solution from u guys .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.fn.androClock = function() {
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  hour = date.getHours();
  return {
    day: days[date.getDay()],
    date: date.getDate(),
    month: months[date.getMonth()],
    hour: appendZero(hour),
    minute: appendZero(date.getMinutes())
  };
}
function appendZero(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  }
  return num;
}
function refreshClock() {
  var now = getTime();
  $('#date').html(now.day + "<br>" + now.date + '. ' + now.month);
  $('#time').html(now.hour + ":" + now.minute);
  setTimeout(function() {
    refreshClock();
  }, 10000);
}
refreshClock();
  };
$('#andro-clock').androClock();

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace military time to normal time with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415618/replace-military-time-to-normal-time-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace military time to normal time with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415618/replace-military-time-to-normal-time-with-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your comments in rahul's answer...

Update the line:

`hour: appendZero(hour),`

to

`hour: appendZero(((hour + 11) % 12) + 1)`  <kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MxtKU/)**</kbd>

---

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhyfQ/1/)**</kbd>

```
var formatTime = (function () {
    function addZero(num) {
        return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
    }

    return function (dt) {
        var formatted = '';

        if (dt) {
            var hours24 = dt.getHours();
            var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
            formatted = [formatted, [addZero(hours), addZero(dt.getMinutes())].join(":"), hours24 > 11 ? "pm" : "am"].join(" ");            
        }
        return formatted;
    }
})();

alert(formatTime(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 4):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNYpV/)

```
function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  hour = date.getHours();
 // var dd = "AM";
  var h = hour;
    if (h > 12) {
        h = hour-12;
   //     dd = "PM";
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    }
  return {
    day: days[date.getDay()],
    date: date.getDate(),
    month: months[date.getMonth()],
    hour: appendZero(h),
    minute: appendZero(date.getMinutes()),
    //  dd: dd  
  };
}


function refreshClock() {
  var now = getTime();
  $('#date').html(now.day + "<br>" + now.date + '. ' + now.month);
 // $('#time').html(now.hour + ":" + now.minute+" "+now.dd);
  $('#time').html(now.hour + ":" + now.minute);
  setTimeout(function() {
    refreshClock();
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: This is what i need  but i dont need am/pm , just the 12 hour time.

Comment: See updated code. commented AP PM logic... If it helped  please accept the answer