# Converting created_at attribute (json object) with underscore

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a JSON object I am trying to convert to a different date format in an underscore template.  Is there a JavaScript function I can call on it? Or do I have to change it on the rails side first before it is converted to a JSON object?

Here is the underscore code in an underscore Template.

```
  <p class='my-well media-body'><%%- comment %><p><p><%%-created_at%></p>
```

Is there a function I can call on the "created_at" to allow me to change the default value (created by the datetime in sql) 2013-12-09T05:28:16.495Z  I would like the time in hours/minutes and the date in mm/dd/yy

I haven't been able to find a strftime type function in JavaScript, but I know there are some in Ruby.  Do I have to change the format before the object is passed in as a JSON object?

My current project is build in a Rails backend and Backbone FrontEnd.

Comment: I think you can use moment.js(a javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates) to format the date from client side.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `var date = new Date(data.created_at)` ?

[Date javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: It's close to what I need.  I don't see how to customize the return values so it only displays the Time(in 12 hour format) mm/dd/yy.  The only thing I see in the docs is to hardcode all the dates.  Using new Date (my_created_at_value) Mon Dec 09 2013 00:28:16 GMT-0500 (EST)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think there is no simple way in JS to get a 12 hours format. (but I'm not a JS Ninja! ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529054/display-time-in-12-hour-format-in-javascript