# Convert Time to ISO to Angular Format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, iso

I am hitting an API and get back JSON data.

I need to change the format the JSON with an angular filter. The format for date I am getting back is: `10/07/2014` and the format of time is: `0745`.

I wrote a angular function called that converted the date to ISO:

```
appController.filter('dateToISO', function(){
return function(input) {
    input = new Date(input).toISOString();
    return input;
};
```

});

Then I use angular filter to render it properly (date = `10/07/2014`:

```
{{outboundFlights.departure_day | dateToISO | date: 'mediumDate'}}
```

and it out puts this:`Oct 7, 2014`

Unfortunately, this does not work for time (time = `0745`):

```
{{outboundFlights.arrival_time | dateToISO  | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

It outputs: `6:00PM`

Any idea why date works, but time doesn't and any possible solution?

I need to convert the time as it is to ISO so I can use the filter correctly.

Comment: I believe you need to change military time format to the normal one first to make it working [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415618/replace-military-time-to-normal-time-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure id it. I had to convert it to a "normal" time out put with a custom filter:

```
appController.filter('timeToNormal', function(){
return function(input) {
    var splitTime   = input.split("");
    var timeFormat  = splitTime[0]+splitTime[1]+":"+splitTime[2]+splitTime[3];
    var newTime     = new Date("June 19, 1987 "+splitTime[0]+splitTime[1]+":"+splitTime[2]+splitTime[3]);
    return newTime;
};});
```

1st I split it into an array, then put a colon `:` between the the 2nd & 3rd number, then pass that through with the normal date filter, with HTML like this:

```
{{outboundFlights.arrival_time | timeToNormal  | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

This then put it an acceptable format for the built-in "date" angular filter to handle.