# Cumbersome time parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime-parsing

I need a function to convert time in text from a format with day-part letters to digits.
E.g. 4:15PM -> 16:15, 4:15AM -> 4:15AM. Currently I have the following solution

```js
function formatTime(text){
 var find = '([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)';
 
 var reg = new RegExp(find, 'g');
 
 pos = 0;

 var result;
 var formatedText = "";
 while((result = reg.exec(text)) !== null) {
  if(result[2] == "PM"){
   var hours= parseInt(result[0], 10);
   hours = hours + 12;
   var hoursStr = hours.toString();
   var newTime = hoursStr + result[0].substring(result[1].length,result[0].length - 3);
   
   formatedText += newTime;
   pos = reg.lastIndex;
  } else {
   formatedText += text.replace("AM","").substring(pos, reg.lastIndex);
   pos = reg.lastIndex;
  }
 }
 
 if(pos < text.length){
  formatedText += text.substring(pos, text.length);
 }
 
 return formatedText;
}

console.log(formatTime("Some Text (11:00AM - 1:00PM)"));
```

I makes nicely cases like 
console.log(formatTime("Some Text (11:00AM - 1:00PM)"));

But I strugle to make it process
console.log(formatTime("Some Text (11:00 AM - 1:00 PM)"));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415618/replace-military-time-to-normal-time-with-javascript

Comment: *E.g. 4:15PM -> 16:15, 4:15AM -> 4:15AM* So if it's it PM you want to convert the hour, but if it's AM you want to **leave** the "AM"" in the result?

Comment: yes, I need it to be formatted like this.

Comment: How come you didn't try to use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? Why reinvent the wheel and waste your valuable time? Libraries exist for a reason, don't hesitate to use them. Arguments such as "it's too big for my needs" or "mine works faster" aren't real arguments. People create free software, we should use it - especially if it saves us our time and lets us focus on our work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your examples.
I've added `\\s?` to the regex and made a minor change in the logic of cutting time (-2 instead of -3). Also I've moved variables definition to the beginning of the function to reflect hoisting in JavaScript.

```
function formatTime(text){
    var find = '([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\\s?(AM|PM)';            
    var reg = new RegExp(find, 'g');            
    var pos = 0;
    var formatedText = "";
    var result, hours, hoursStr, newTime;           

    while ((result = reg.exec(text)) !== null) {
        if (result[2] === "PM") {
            hours= parseInt(result[0], 10);
            hours = hours + 12;
            hoursStr = hours.toString();
            newTime = hoursStr + result[0].substring(result[1].length, result[0].length - 2);

            formatedText += newTime;                    
        } else {
            formatedText += text.replace("AM","").substring(pos, reg.lastIndex);

        }

        pos = reg.lastIndex;
    }

    if (pos < text.length) {
        formatedText += text.substring(pos, text.length);
    }

    return formatedText;
}
```

Comment: Works why, because you did what? Why did you not clean up his regexp for him, or fix it to use a regexp literal as he should? What is the purpose of the `g` flag, and why is there a loop around `reg.exec`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to do this:  Just use two functions. One to convert the hours, and another to match against `PM` times along with the `replace()` function.

Easy does it...

```js
function convertTime12to24(time12h) {
  const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');

  let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');

  if (hours === '12') {
    hours = '00';
  }

  if (modifier === 'PM') {
    hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
  }

  return hours + ':' + minutes;
}


function formatTime(i_string) {
  console.log(i_string.replace(/([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(PM)/gi, function newDate(x) {

    return convertTime12to24(x.replace("PM", " PM"))
  }));
}
formatTime("The time is now 4:15PM");
formatTime("The time is now 12:15PM");
formatTime("The time is now 4:00AM");
formatTime("The time is now 12:00AM");
formatTime("The time is now 11:00PM");
```

Comment: But according to OP, he wants to **retain** the "AM". Also, your code seems to be removing the space following the dash.

Comment: I simply wanted to point in the right direction - this site really isn't for creating production quality answers for people -- its for helping solve their programming issues -- since I dont know/care how their algorithm works or how it manages to derive the output, I simply noted the typo and then made a correction where it appeared there was a hard coded value which depended on the typo. I would probably do it a different way using  the `:`  as a separator then just adding 12 if its PM to the hour part but whatever

Comment: @torazaburo also it does not say that they want to retain the AM/PM in the OP -- it says  4:15PM ->  16:15

Comment: The original post clearly says *4:15AM -> 4:15AM*, preserving the "AM", and the OP confirmed that in a comment.

Comment: im re-writing the code to make it way easier -- this is a terrible answer anywas